# How does flow differ from or relates to attention?

Tags: attention, flow

Csikszentmihalyi introduced the notion of [flow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_(psychology)), which is almost certainly his best known work/concept.

Despite the fact that Wikipedia has a *very* long article on flow, I can't find a simple explanation in there how flow relates to attention, other than it might be just "effortless attention".

Is this all there is to it? Are there any more in-depth explanations how the two concepts relate or interact?

---

After paying slightly more attention to the wiki page, the "effortless" bit actually involves a whole motivational loop, so that there's an appearance of lack of effort. So, no deep motivation, no flow. But still I'd like to know if Csikszentmihalyi's flow, which is very highly cited (his books are that is) has been related to other more common concepts...